# Cell editor in a datatable is getting only one value in JSF

Tags: jquery, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

Am trying to select some items from a datatable using selection mode and also specify the quantity of the items i selected using CellEditor, but the CellEditor is not getting all the values i entered after clicking the "Show" button, it's only getting the last value i entered in the CellEditor's column. Please i need someone to help me out!!!

My XHTML code

```
<p:dataTable  editable="true"  editMode="cell"  id="change" selection="#{openJobOrderBean.selectedMaterials}"  rowKey="#{openJob.materialId}"
              rows="5" var="openJob" value="#{openJobOrderBean.smtOrder}" paginator="true" paginatorPosition="bottom"
              paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
              rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15">

    <p:ajax immediate="true" process="@this" event="cellEdit" listener="#{openJobOrderBean.onCellEdit}" update="change" />
    <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="text-align: center; width: 80px" headerText="Select Requested Materials" />
    <p:column headerText="Quantity Requested(click to edit)" style="width: 150px; text-align: center" class="columnedit" >
        <p:cellEditor>
            <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{openJobOrderBean.quantity}" /></f:facet>
            <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText label="Quantity Requested(editable)" value="#{openJobOrderBean.quantity}" style="width: 150px" />

            </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>
    </p:column>

    <p:column style="text-align: center" headerText="Material Name" filterBy="#{openJob.materialName}">
        <h:outputText value="#{openJob.materialName}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column style="text-align: center" headerText="Available Quantity" >
        <h:outputText value="#{openJob.materialQuantity}" />
    </p:column>
    <f:facet name="footer">
        <p:commandButton id="shows" oncomplete="PF('multimaterials').show()" value="Show" process="change" update=":mainform:materialdetails"/> 
    </f:facet>
</p:dataTable>

<p:dialog header="Selected Materials" widgetVar="multimaterials" minimizable="true" maximizable="true"
          showEffect="shake" hideEffect="explode"  width="500">
    <p:panel style="width: 500px" id="materialdetails" >

        <ui:repeat  value="#{openJobOrderBean.selectedMaterials}" var="openJob">

            <p:panelGrid columns="1" layout="grid">
                         #{openJob.materialName} - #{openJobOrderBean.quantity}
            </p:panelGrid>

        </ui:repeat>
    </p:panel>
</p:dialog>
```

My Bean

```
 private List<OpenJobOrderBean> powerHouseOrder;
  private List<OpenJobOrderBean> selectedMaterials;
private String materialName;
private int materialQuantity;
private int materialId;
private int quantity;

public String getMaterialName() {
    return materialName;
}

public void setMaterialName(String materialName) {
    this.materialName = materialName;
}

public int getMaterialQuantity() {
    return materialQuantity;
}

public void setMaterialQuantity(int materialQuantity) {
    this.materialQuantity = materialQuantity;
}

public int getMaterialId() {
    return materialId;
}

public void setMaterialId(int materialId) {
    this.materialId = materialId;
}

public int getQuantity() {
    return quantity;
}

public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
    this.quantity = quantity;
}

 public List<OpenJobOrderBean> getSelectedMaterials() {
  return selectedMaterials;
}

public void setSelectedMaterials(List<OpenJobOrderBean> selectedMaterials) {
    this.selectedMaterials = selectedMaterials;
}

public List<OpenJobOrderBean> getPowerHouseOrder() {
    try {
        this.powerHouseOrder = new OpenJobOrder().retrievePowerHouseMaterials();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "", e.getMessage());
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
    }
    return powerHouseOrder;
}

public void onCellEdit(CellEditEvent event) {
    Object oldValue = event.getOldValue();
    Object newValue = event.getNewValue();
    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Cell Changed", "Old: " + oldValue + ", New:" + newValue);
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);

}
```

[This is the result before clicking the SHOW button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmaUb.png)

[This is the result after selecting and clicking the SHOW button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekdcj.png)

Answer (score 0):

Why did you do this?

```
#{openJob.materialName} - #{openJobOrderBean.quantity}
```

To get the quantity of the job, you have to change to:

```
#{openJob.materialName} - #{openJob.quantity}
```

Also, this looks really bad. Do not store a list of your bean. Create an entity class for openJob and store a list of these entities..

Comment: I have changed to :

`#{openJob.materialName} - #{openJob.quantity}`

but it's getting 0 as the quantity all through.
@Attila

Comment: Please i don't understand what you meant by creating an entity class for openJob...

Comment: You should change to #{openJob.quantity} in cellEditor as well.. 
By creating an entity class, i mean you should create a class which has all the attributes (name,quantity,id,etc.) and the getter/setter methods and you are storing a list of these in your bean. You should have ONE bean for your xhtml page, and not storing a list of beans in the same bean.